# Remove headsepline if no text is displayed on the header

Tags: header-footer, scrlayer-scrpage

I'm new here and I got a problem I can't solve myself despite Google and Co.

By far I created a header which consist of the current chapter name on the left side of a twoside document and the section name on the right page with a header separation line.

The code below show the used KomaOptions for the `\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}`

```
\KOMAoptions{automark
    headsepline=true,   % header line
    footsepline=false,          % footer line
    cleardoublepage=plain,  % set empty pages to style 'plain'
    plainheadsepline=false, % activate header line for plain pages
    plainfootsepline=false} % activate footer line for plain pages


\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot

\lehead{\headmark{}}
\rohead{\headmark{}}
\ofoot*{\pagemark}
```

However, how to get rid of the head separation line if no section name on the left page of the document isn't printed?
The following pictures shall illustrate the issue.

The first one is fine, as it contains a section name at least.

[image: Perfect]

The second picture, prints the head separation line. How to remove it?

[image: Not perfect]

Here the MWE

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage} % Koma header and footer package

\KOMAoptions{headsepline=true,  % header line
    footsepline=false,          % footer line
    cleardoublepage=plain,  % set empty pages to style 'plain'
    plainheadsepline=false, % activate header line for plain pages
    plainfootsepline=false} % activate footer line for plain pages


\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot

\lehead{\headmark{}}
\rohead{\headmark{}}
\ofoot*{\pagemark}


\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\chapter{Anhang}
\lipsum
\section{Infos}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please update your question to include a complete compilable minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225/117050))! It begins at `\documentclass` and ends at `\end{document}` including all necessary packages and commands to produce a minimal setup that shows what you've got so far!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following checks whether `\headmark` has the width of 0pt, and if so, changes the color of the `headsepline` to white:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrbook}

\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\KOMAoptions{%
    headsepline=true,   % header line
    footsepline=false,          % footer line
    cleardoublepage=plain,  % set empty pages to style 'plain'
    plainheadsepline=false, % activate header line for plain pages
    plainfootsepline=false} % activate footer line for plain pages


\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot

\newcommand*{\specialheadmark}{%
    \setbox0\hbox{\headmark}%
    \ifdim\wd0=0pt\relax%
        \global\setkomafont{headsepline}{\color{white}}%
    \else%
        \global\setkomafont{headsepline}{\color{black}}%
    \fi%
    \unhbox0%
}

\lehead{\specialheadmark}
\rohead{\specialheadmark}
\ofoot*{\pagemark}

\usepackage{blindtext}


\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\chapter{Foo}
\clearpage
\blindtext
\clearpage
\blindtext
\clearpage
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Pages 6 and 7:

[image]

Comment: Works like charm :D! May I ask you did you manage to learn latex this easily. Is their are good manual how to learn those things?

Comment: @Joe it's mostly read, try, read, read and try... Read a short introduction which is up to date. Read the documentation of the packages you use. And so on. On this site are a few question related to learning LaTeX. Search for them and find something that is up to your taste.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another suggestion disabeling the `headsepline` on a page if `\headmark` is empty:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets pagestyle scrheadings automatically

\KOMAoptions{headsepline=true}
\AddToLayerPageStyleOptions{scrheadings}
  {oninit={% will be excecuted whenever the output of the layers is initialized
    \ifstr{\headmark}{}{\KOMAoptions{headsepline=false}}{}%
  }}

\clearpairofpagestyles

\ohead{\headmark}
\ofoot*{\pagemark}

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\chapter{Foo}
\Blindtext[20]
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Note that `\clearscrheadfoot` is a command of the outdated package `scrpage2`. It only works for compatibility reasons. I have replaced it by `\clearpairofpagestyles`.

Comment: And one clearly sees, that you have much more knowledge of KOMA than I have. Great answer!